# Good graph theory and combinatorics book

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, textbook-recommendation

I am looking for a book about graph theory and combinatorics. I am studying the routing problem in communication networks, therefore my interest is on a book with a wide set of problems and examples.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Better ask this question on math.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Combinatorics and Graph Theory](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387797106)

> This book covers a wide variety of topics in combinatorics and graph
>   theory. It includes results and problems that cross subdisciplines,
>   emphasizing relationships between different areas of mathematics.